# Swiftui Preview inspect size

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I might be remembering wrong, but in an earlier version of Xcode Swift-UI previews I recall you could see the size of the selected view.

Is there a way to get see this currently?

Comment: Try using GeometryReader to get the size of a view.

Comment: I don't remember ever being able to do this. You can always run your app and use the UI inspector/debugger thingy instead.